# Magento2, overriding braintree PaymentMethod for partial payment

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, partial-payments

In order to make the partial payment possible, should custom module override `PaymentMethod.php` file in below path? How would be `for` and `type` in `di.xml`?

```
/vendor/braintree/braintree_php/lib/Braintree/PaymentMethod.php
```

In di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="vendor\braintree\braintree_php\lib\Braintree\PaymentMethod" type="Myvendor\myModule\lib\CustomPaymentMethod" />
</config>
```

CustomPaymentMethod.php

```
<?php
namespace Myvendor\myModule\lib;

class CustomPaymentMethod extends Base
{
    protected $_canCapture                  = true;
    protected $_canCapturePartial           = true;

    // static methods redirecting to gateway

    public static function create($attribs)
    {
        return Configuration::gateway()->paymentMethod()->create($attribs);
    }

    public static function find($token)
    {
        return Configuration::gateway()->paymentMethod()->find($token);
    }

    public static function update($token, $attribs)
    {
        return Configuration::gateway()->paymentMethod()->update($token, $attribs);
    }

    public static function delete($token)
    {
        return Configuration::gateway()->paymentMethod()->delete($token);
    }
}
class_alias('Braintree\PaymentMethod', 'Braintree_PaymentMethod');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want to use partial capturing for Braintree.

Braintree officially doesn't support partial capturing, this is restricted feature, but they have that functionality [Transaction::submitForPartialSettlement()](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php/blob/master/lib/Braintree/Transaction.php#L545).

But Magento Braintree implementation supports the partial capturing (it uses some strategies to resolve capture operations), so if you need this feature, you don't need to override any code in Braintree SDK.